# Translation help of gravestone

Tags: translation, kanji, kana

I'm still learning Japanese so many of these kanji I can't even make out.
This is the back of my great uncles grave in Hawaii and I'd appreciate if I can get the kana and English translations.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It says:

「千九百七年六月十二日{せんきゅうひゃくななねんろくがつじゅうににち}

米領布哇{べいりょうハワイ}ニ於{おい}テ出生{しゅっせい}

千九百三十八年七月七日{せんきゅうひゃくさんじゅうはちねんしちがつなのか}

ミシガン大學病院{だいがくびょういん}ニテ永眠{えいみん}」

It means:

"June 12th, 1907

Born in Hawaii, U.S.A.

July 7th, 1938

Deceased at the University of Michigan Hospital"

Comment: Oh wow, That's interesting cause the front already had the birth and death dates. So, this isn't new info but thank you! I can add it to my heritage profile in full now.